# Laravel websockets failed to connect in pusher

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

When I run my project, I got an exception error but it does not have a clear message. I only have this kind of the main body error

I can access websocket admin page at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets` but when i go `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` i got errors below.

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://127.0.0.1:6001/apps/995591/events?

Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.

The system returned: (111) Connection refused


The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Generated Tue, 05 May 2020 17:12:03 GMT by proxyserversetup-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-07 (squid/3.5.27)
```

I followed every single thing in the docs from [this link](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#using-a-different-port)

Here are some of my config

broadcasting.php

```
 'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=inventory
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=995591
PUSHER_APP_KEY=644a4ac1988060882370
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=739696537f4fb23b8fcd
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

I am using laravel 6.x and the current version for laravel websockets.

Is it my ISP cause the error?

Comment: Have you also configured the WebSocket app? (to accept those keys) https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/pusher.html#configuring-websocket-apps

Comment: i have that already in my `websockets.php`

Answer (score 8):

I had something similar to this happen to me.

If you are using `localhost`, change

```php
'useTLS' => true,
```

to false

```php
'useTLS' => false,
```

It should be in your broadcasting.php file

```php
'connections' => [
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => false,
        ],
    ],
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Making sure you set scheme to https and use 'useTLS' => true then setting up curl_options like below if you set up the paths for SSL certificate & private key.

```
    'curl_options' => [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the `PUSHER_PORT` data in the `.env` file:

```
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6379
```

Verify using CLI in the docroot with `artisan` command for web socket:

```php
php artisan websockets:serve --port=6379
```