# staging.ERROR: Failed to connect to Pusher on staging, but working fine on localhost

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm recently getting this error on the staging server when broadcasting a message via `Pusher:`

```
staging.ERROR: Failed to connect to Pusher. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException(code: 0): Failed to connect to Pusher.
```

Weird thing is, everything works fine on `localhost`, and API messages are getting to the Pusher debug console. When I try do to it on staging, with the same code and configuration, I get the error message above. I assume that this has to do something with broadcasting configuration, but I'm not sure what to do here. This is my current pusher config in `broadcasting.php` (`.env` configuration is fine, double-checked):

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

I've been playing with different configuration options, such as setting `useTLS` to `true` or `false`, setting `scheme` to `http` or `https`, setting `curl_options`, setting `encrypted` to `true` or `false`, but I didn't get any results, my messages weren't registering in Pusher debug console, even tho Subscribed events are registering properly, as seen here: [image: this image]

I appreciate any help. If someone needs any more info about the code and configuration, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

change this line in your config/broadcasting.php:

```
'useTLS' => false //Make sure its false
```

clear cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

please check this answer:
[Laravel websockets failed to connect in pusher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618183/laravel-websockets-failed-to-connect-in-pusher)